# How can I navigate to an InterfaceController from a custom TableRow with WatchKit?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I'm facing a little issue with WatchKit.
I'm trying to push a controller from a custom table row (extending `NSObject`); the problem is, the `pushController` method (which allows to navigate to a new page) can be used only in an instance of the `WKinterfaceController` class, but I want to do it from my custom row (so an instance of NSObject).

The Custom Table Row's code looks like:

```swift
import Foundation
import WatchKit

class CustomRowController : NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    
    @IBAction func onButtonTapped() {
        // Push action should go here
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I ended up using this workaround instead:

```swift
let items = [0, 1]
tableView.setNumberOfRows(items.count, withRowType: "row_type")
        
for index in items {
    let row = tableView.rowController(at: index) as! CustomRowController
    row.parent = self       
}
```

Then edited my CustomRowController so i can navigate using the parent WKInterfaceController instance like:

```swift
import Foundation
import WatchKit

class CustomRowController : NSObject {
    var parent: WKInterfaceController?
    @IBOutlet weak var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    
    @IBAction func onButtonTapped() {
        // Push action should go here
        parent?.pushController(withName: "name", context: nil)
    }
}
```

It's working but, is there a better way to do this?